# Zend Framework - Message: The supplied parameters to Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I get this Error:

> Message: The supplied parameters to Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed
>   to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names
>   for validity.

Public:

```
protected function _getAuthAdapter()
{
    $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

    $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(CONCAT(?,salt))');

    return $authAdapter;
}
```

Tutorial from: http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/

Comment: Do some debugging. Find where that message is being generated. Dump the sql and find out why it's being treated as invalid. Dump the show create table for users.

Comment: object(Zend_Auth_Result)[70]
  protected '_code' => int -3
  protected '_identity' => string 'admin' (length=5)
  protected '_messages' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Supplied credential is invalid.' (length=31)

Comment: You're still deep in the framework. Keep stepping back through 'Supplied credential is invalid' until you come across your logical error.

Comment: Its 1:1 from the Tutorial. I doesn't find a logical error.

Comment: There's only 2 kinds of errors http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error. Since you're not seeing a PHP or MySQL message it falls in the category of the former. A tutorial written 3+ years ago for an older framework certainly leaves room for things to change. Read about fixing logical errors and you'll see they recommend hand-debugging like I was saying.

Comment: So works, but result is ever false... :

 protected function _getAuthAdapter() {

        $dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

        $authAdapter->setTableName('users')
                ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(salt)');

        return $authAdapter;
    }

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem of the concatenated string, try this work over

```
->setCredentialTreatment("SHA1(CAST(CONCAT(?,salt) AS CHAR))");
```